# Add file watermark as it's uploaded

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, file-upload, event-receivers, events

I've been trying to add a watermark to files as they are uploaded to SharePoint.
I tried using several events:
ItemAdding, ItemUpdating, ItemCheckedIn.

In ItemUpdating and ItemCheckedIn the file is already in the DB. so I can add a watermark - but it's just a waste of DB read/write (The whole file is written, then I read it, then I re-save it to the db).

the ItemAdding event looks good, it does rise before the content is saved to the DB, but I do not have the content itself (SPItemEventProperties doesn't have any "content" attribute or something similar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the content from the ItemAdding event by using Request.Files property of the context. Try something like this :

```
HttpFileCollection files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;  
    foreach (String key in files.Keys)   
    {  
        if (collection[key].ContentLength > 0)   
        {  
           Stream stream = files[key].InputStream;  
           string filePath = files[key].FileName;  
        }  
    }
```

For more info, read [this post](http://khdraft.blogspot.co.il/2011/04/getting-file-content-from-itemadding.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [ItemAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadded.aspx) event instead?  This fires after the item has finished being added to the library.

Comment: The real questions is - where do I get the content from in the ItemAdded event. Let's say I'm uploading a file to a document library, in the ItemAdded event, where can I see its content to add the water mark?

Comment: You should be able to get everything you need from properties.ListItem.File (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.file)

Comment: Checked it out - it's just like ItemCheckingIn and ItemUpdating - the file is already in the DB at this point, which means I'm doing extra read & rewrite for every file. that's a huge performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this task during ItemAdded Event.
You juts need to set

```
"<Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>"
```

in Element.xml file of Event receiver.

```
<Receivers  ListUrl="Lists\Doc">      
      <Receiver>
        <Name>List_EventItemAdded</Name>
        <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>DocumentLib_EventReceiver.List_Event.List_Event</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
        **<Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>**
      </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on how to access the content of the file during this event, just to have a complete answer? Thanks.

Comment: Basically, After File Upload in SharePoint Document Library, you find hard to trap the ItemAdded Event. Then you need to use <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization> trapping the file upload. At this time, The file is already uploaded in document library but you can set properties, or retrieve file.